# Why is content-type case sensitive when set in HttpServletResponse.setContentType

Tags: java, html, browser

Why is the content type passed to HttpServletResponse.setContentType() case sensitive when the official HTTP documentation says that Header fields are case-insensetive.

E.g.

```
HttpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json"); //Returns JSON

HttpServletResponse.setContentType("application/Json"); //Returns text
```

> Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>
> 4.2 Message Headers
>
> HTTP header fields, which include general-header (section 4.5),
>   request-header (section 5.3), response-header (section 6.2), and
>   entity-header (section 7.1) fields, follow the same generic format as
>   that given in Section 3.1 of RFC 822 [9]. Each header field consists
>   of a name followed by a colon (":") and the field value. Field names
>   are **case-insensitive**.

Comment: It says that only the header names are case-insensitive. The values on the other-hand are case sensitive.

Comment: Yeah, only field names are non-case-sensitive. So you can use `ConTENT-TyPE`, for example.